# Difference between creating a System.Windows.Forms.Timer with or without a container?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that uses a few timers. I noticed that the forms designer passes in a container:

```
_someTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(components);
```

When I've created timers without using Designer, I used the default constructor:

```
_otherTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
```

I've never noticed any difference. Can anyone explain what difference it makes when a container is passed in upon construction?

Comment: The [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Timer__ctor_System_ComponentModel_IContainer_) explains what passing in the container does (it ties the lifetime of the timer to it). When you don't pass the container, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Docs was the first thing I looked at, but somehow I missed the remarks. :-(

Comment: If you open the Designer.cs file, you'll see that the Dispose() procedure disposes of the `components` collection. If you don't add a Component to this collection, you simply need to dispose of it yourself, usually when the Form closes (`OnFormClosed`) or when the Component is not needed anymore. You also have to unsubscribe to the events you have subscribed to. So, it's a way to automate this procedure. If you drop a Component (not a Control) into a Form, this is done by the Form designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It disposes with the container according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Timer__ctor_System_ComponentModel_IContainer_)

### Remarks

The Timer constructor enables you to associate a Timer with any Container object. By associating the Timer like this, you hand over control of the lifetime of the Timer to the Container. This can be useful if you use a number of components in your application and want to dispose of all of them simultaneously. For example, if you associate a ToolTip, an ImageList, and a Timer with a Container, calling Dispose on the Container will force disposal of all of these components as well.

This instance will exist until its container releases it to garbage collection.